# Scikit-learn average_precision_score() vs. auc score of precision_recall_curve()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model-evaluations

I've been searching around for an explanation to this, and haven't come across one yet- in scikit-learn, when I compute the `auc()` of the `precision_recall_curve()`, I get a different macro-metric than when I use the builtin `average_precision_score()` function. As per the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score), this makes sense, due to `auc()` using a trapezoidal approximation, and thus average precision being more accurate. However, when I compute the micro-metrics, the values are the same. I'm trying to understand this.

Here's an example:

```
yhat_raw = np.array([[0.511, 0.62, 0.3],[0.11, 0.76, 0.945],[0.002, 0.671, 0.452],[0.9102, 0.783, 0.2]])
y = np.array([[0, 1, 1],[0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 1]])
yhatmic = yhat_raw.ravel()
ymic = y.ravel()
prec["micro"], rec["micro"], _ = precision_recall_curve(ymic, yhatmic, 
pos_label=1)
```

`auc(rec["micro"], prec["micro"])`
returns `0.58305555555555544`.
`average_precision_score(ymic, yhatmic)` returns `0.62222222222222223`.

Upon actually deploying the model, these metrics are coming to the same thing. I think this makes sense, considering that at a larger scale (e.g. along a dimension of thousands of datapoints rather than `len(rec['micro']) = 11` datapoints in this example), the trapezoidal approximation is much closer to the true value.

My question is, why do the metrics then differ in the `macro` case? Is it fair to say that in a real-world deployment, the micro-evaluation has enough datapoints for the trapezoidal approximation to converge to the true value, but the macro- does not (computed across ~3000 test examples, with a label space of ~2000 labels)?

Answer (score 0):

The metrics differ in the `macro` case because [`macro` in scikit-learn ignores class imbalances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html). `micro` in scikit-learn looks at global rates. The data has class imbalances, thus the `macro` argument will return different values compared to `micro`.